# meteor how to render script tags to include full domain name

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using meteor with blaze. 
Currently in the rendered templates, the scripts files are included as 
src="/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285"
src="/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4"

Is there anyway to change that to include the fully qualified domain name, such as: http://exmaple.com//packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is your requirement for using the fully qualified domain name? This ties your application to a specific domain and could cause problems down the road if you need to migrate to a new domain name.

Comment: I am trying create proxy page for a shopify app. When the app is installed by a shop own, it will call the proxy page, which in term request the page I am trying to create. Because different shop owners can use different domains or main url, so when the proxy request my page, it can't find the actual scripts or css files because they don't exist in those domains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen this done. You can make a package and include `templating` in your `api.use`. Then, you create an HTML file.

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  // ...
  api.use('templating', 'client');
  api.addFiles('client.html', 'client');
});
```

In the html file, you can include a `<head>` tag with a `<script>` to your resource

```
<head>
  <script src="http://someresource.com"></script>
</head>
```

For reference, check out the repo for [mrgalaxy:stripe](https://github.com/tyler-johnson/stripe-meteor), which is required to include a resource linked from Stripe's site.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think that's what I am trying to achieve. That will add external sources in addition to original meteor js files. But it won't render the meteor js files source in their full URLs.